# Multiple checkbox values handling with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to learn ReactJS and creating a little chore list which adds the name of the chore and the days when the chore should be done.

But I can't figure out how to get an array of the checked checkboxes when handling the submit of the form.

What I'd like is to have an array of all checked values in my newChore.handleSubmit.

```
var NewChore = React.createClass({
    handleSubmit: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = this.refs.name.value;
        console.log(this.refs.test);
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <form className="ChoreForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="name">Naam</label>
                    <input type="text" ref="name" id="name" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Day number="1" name="Monday" ref="test" />
                    <Day number="2" name="Tuesday" ref="test" />
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Opslaan" />
            </form>
        );
    }
});

var Day = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (<div>
            <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleChange} ref="day_number" id="day_{this.props.number}" /><label htmlFor="day_{this.props.number}">{this.props.name}</label>
        </div>);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the function also in props like you have to declare handle change function in your parent component like:

```js
var NewChore = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = this.refs.name.value;
    console.log(this.refs.test);
  },
  handleChange: function (e) {
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <form className="ChoreForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="name">Naam</label>
          <input type="text" ref="name" id="name" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Day number="1" name="Monday" ref="test" onHandleChange={this.handleChange} />
          <Day number="2" name="Tuesday" ref="test" onHandleChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Opslaan" />
      </form>
    );
  }
});
```

and Pass this function to your child component like

```js
<Day number="1" name="Monday" ref="test" onHandleChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

and use into your child component

```js
var Day = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (<div>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.props.onHandleChange} ref="day_number" id="day_{this.props.number}" /><label htmlFor="day_{this.props.number}">{this.props.name}</label>
    </div>);
  }
});
```

Comment: I think this has to be the way yes. Should I keep up an array in my data with what is becoming checked/unchecked etc, right? Seems kinda overkill for such a simple list of checkboxes, though. P.S: Don't forget to add the attribute to <Day /> for the onchange prop

Comment: yes you have to maintain the checked and unchecked element