# ReactJS: Get multiple checkboxes value with material-ui

Tags: function, reactjs, checkbox, material-ui

How to get multiple checkboxes value ? Ref not working in material ui checkbox, no idea why.

```
<Checkbox key={i} label={catagory.name} ref="categories" value={catagory_name} name="category"  />
```

for example : [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjCsp.png)

Without material-ui you can get the value by ref, but with material-ui it require another method to get checkbox value.

I get the data from API, so it will add more from time to time. How to get the value? What function I should write? Anyone know ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple checkbox values handling with ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607010/multiple-checkbox-values-handling-with-reactjs)

Comment: that one ain't material ui checkbox

Comment: My apologies. However, it does carefully say "possible" duplicate. Best of luck with your code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use build-in Material UI checkbox function - `onChange`. It will return the specified *category* and it's *value*.

`app.js`

```
class App extends Component {

  result = new Set();

  handleCheckbox(event, isChecked, value) {
    console.log(isChecked, value); 
    this.res.add(value);
    if (this.res.size === 3) console.log(this.res);
  }

  labelList = [{id: 1, category: 'a'}, {id: 2, category: 'b'}, {id: 3, category: 'c'}]; // your data

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.labelList.map(element => (
          <CheckboxField
            key={element.id}
            label={element.category}
            category={element.category}
            onChange={this.handleCheckbox}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

`Checkbox.js`

```
export class CheckboxField extends React.PureComponent {

  handleCheck = (event, isInputChecked) => {
    this.props.onChange(event, isInputChecked, this.props.category);
  };

  render() {
    return (
          <Checkbox
            label={this.props.category}
            iconStyle={{fill: '#000'}}
            value={this.props.category}
            onCheck={this.handleCheck}
          />
    )}
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro! You just saved my time!

Comment: How to make it array ? eg:[a, b, c]

Comment: @Alan Still having problems?

Comment: @Alan Get array? You want to get array after checking all checkboxes? Array of what?

Comment: i want all 3 values in an array after checked and post to database. So I need array of the values of checkbox been checked. Can get what I mean ?

Comment: @Alan After checking all checkboxes, yeah?

Comment: 2 issues: 

 1. checkboxes are not inline . i even tries setting style with style property `<CheckboxField style ={{display:'inline'}}
            key={element.id}
            label={element.category}
            category={element.category}
            onChange={this.handleCheckbox}
          />`  
2. Checkboxes and labels are wide apart